# upper_bound and lower_bound in different headers?

Tags: c++, std

`lower_bound` doesn't give any error, but `upper_bound` does. On searching, it's present in `<algorithm>` headers file.

Why the inconsistency? would be interesting to know.

C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>                                                
#include <vector>     
using namespace std;                                               
int main() {                                                       
    vector<int> ans={1,5,7,8};                                     
    cout<< upper_bound(ans.begin(), ans.end(), 16) -ans.begin() <<endl;
    cout<< lower_bound(ans.begin(), ans.end(), 16) -ans.begin() <<endl;
    return 0;                                                      
}
```

Output:

```
/tmp/a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/tmp/a.cpp:7:50: error: ‘upper_bound’ was not declared in this scope
     cout<< upper_bound(ans.begin(), ans.end(), 16) <<endl;
```

**EDIT**

```
$ g++ -v
gcc version 5.2.1 20151010 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2)
```

Comment: Both are defined in `<algorithm>`. The fact that you're able to access one of them without including the header says... something about your implementation, but nothing about C++ in general.

Comment: What compiler? This online Visual C++ compiler won't compile either without including `algorithm`: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ . This is probably an implementation artifact due to some other code included via `iostream` or `vector` forward declaring `lower_bound()` but not `upper_bound()`.

Comment: Btw, did really just create two tags for this question? Why do you think they are useful?

Comment: @Baum 'upper_bound' and 'lower_bound' with respect to stl can have many questions.

Comment: @mtk: Sure, but nobody can be a specialist in "upper_bound". So no tags for those.

Comment: Why? Possibly something you included contains a forward define for `lower_bound` because they needed it and couldn't be bothered to include algorithm for some reason. Happens sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

When you include any std header, any and all symbols from std may be imported.

Basically, all you are guaranteed is that the symbols in the header you ask for will be available.  Extra can come to.

So this is conforming.